# Is it possible to use fsolve if an existing script return a class structure?

Tags: matlab

I have a script Function.m such that for example, when I write `TEST=Function(1,2)`, I have `TEST.x1=4` and `TEST.x2=[5,6,7]`. I want to use `fsolve` to help me find input. To be precise, I want to define a function, say `a=@(y)Function(1,y)-4` so that when I use `[z,vector]=fsolve(@(y)a(y),5)`, matlab can help me to obtain `z=2` and `vector=[5,6,7]`.

I would like to solve it by defining the same structure New_Function.m as Function.m such that it returns `x1` values, i.e., `TEST=New_Function(1,2)` gives `TEST=4` only. Then I write `new_a=@(y)New_Function(1,y)-4` and solve `z=fsolve(@(y)new_a(y),5)` and define `new_vector=Function(1,z)` so that I can access `new_vector.x2`.

I want to know if it is possible to do my task without defining a new script or amending the content in the existing script. How to write code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Matlab does not allow further referencing the result of a function call, you may need to help yourself with `getfield`. In your example (provided I got it right), it would be something like `New_Func = @(y) getfield(Function(1,y),'x1')`. This would take one scalar and return one scalar, i.e., `New_Func(y)` gives the field value of the struct returned by `Function(1,y)` associated to the field `x1`.

Comment: I see. That's what I want to have. But I would like to move one more step: Is it possible to get the vector x2 as well? I know I can get the vector after I solve it and substitute z in the Function, but it would be better if I solve it using fsolve and store vector simultaneously. Indeed, I would like [z=2,vector=[5,6,7]] for my later analysis and I need to repeat the procedure for 1000 times. It may be time consuming if I need to recalculate each time.

Comment: Hm, i wouldn't know how - `fsolve` outputs the optimal point and the function value of the function it's optimizing. Since we just abstracted away the `x2`, the `fsolve` cannot know anything of its existence let alone return it. There might be some nasty hacks involving global variables, but I'm not going to advocate using any of that.